# Change of variable values in Python without explicit changing them

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
    U_abs = abs(U)
    index_max = np.argmax(U_abs[k:n,k])
    memory_1 = U[k:n,k]    
    memory_2 = U[k:n,indice_max]
    print(memory_1)
    print(memory_2)
    U[k:n,k]  = memory_2
    U[k:n,indice_max]= memory_1
    print(memory_1)
    print(memory_2)
```

I need the values of `memory_1` and `memory_2` not to change, but when I change the values of  `U[k:n,k]`  and `U[k:n,index_max]` the values of `memory_1` and `memory_2` change. This is my first day in Python. Any idea in how to fix this?

Comment: Some more context and the actual output of this would help

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that everything you're doing here is using NumPy. If so, you can replace lines 3 and 4 with the copy operator:

```
memory_1 = U[k:n,k].copy()  
memory_2 = U[k:n,indice_max].copy()
```